# how to design rows and columns for a dynamic org chart- thoughts more than puzzle to solve

Tags: javascript, jquery

progress: https://jsfiddle.net/zigzag/ptpyp66L/12/

the jQuery code that does the show/hide:

```
    $('.menu-toggle').click( function(){
   $(this).find('span').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-bottom').toggleClass('glyphicon-triangle-right');
   $(this).closest( ".card" ).closest( ".row " ).nextAll( ".row" ).toggle();

   $(this).closest( ".card" ).parent().nextAll().toggle(); 
});
```

How can I, first of all, show other boxes like this to the (left and right) side of Adam and then also have these caret buttons continue to only show/hide the objects underneath. Furthermore, I'll want this chart to change dynamically based on JSON data feed (as personnel, title and structure changes over time). What is the best way to approach this type of design challenge. use flexbox? bootstrap? If I can get the front end to work, the rest is easier. I know there are some plugins out there but not all of them are flexible enough to meet specific design need thats when I started out doing this from scratch. Thanks for reading.

Comment: There are numerous org chart libraries around you can use

Comment: No doubt. what is the plugin you recommend that closely matches our layout for picture on left, and user details on right. with collapse/expand capability for parent/child nodes.